# Single line nesting for loops in a Python Dict

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models: Sites and Regions. A Region has many Sites.

```
class Site(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Region(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  sites = models.ManyToManyField('Site')
```

i would like to loop through the queryset so as to get a dict (which will eventually become JSON) that looks like this:

```
regions = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Region 1",
        sites: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Site 1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Site 2"
            }
        ]
    },{
        id: 2,
        name: "Region 2",
        sites: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Site 3"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Site 4"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

The thing is, I would like to do it in one line. I feel like I'm on the right track with `{Region.name : {int(Site.id) : Site.name for Site in Region.sites.all()} for Region in Region.objects.all()}` but I'm having trouble nesting the loops. I feel like it should be something like the below, but this is not working:

```
{ 'id' : Region.id, 'name': Region.name, 'children' : { 'id': int(Site.id), 'name' : Site.name} for Site in Site.objects.all()} for Region in Region.objects.all()}
```

Comment: You could utilize [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) function on your querysets

Comment: imo, list comprehensions are incredibly convenient, but become very difficult to read once you start nesting them. Why not just add a classmethod to your `Region` class to return the values the way you need so you can use a one-liner in your view?

Comment: Brandon, could you elaborate on that a little please?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but maybe you want something like:

```
regions = [dict(r.items() + [('sites', r.site_set.all().values('id', 'name'))]) for r in Record.objects.all().values('id', 'name')]
```

UPD. But as Brandon noted, it would be better to not use such complicated oneliners.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{'id' : region.id, 'name': region.name, 'sites' : { 'id': int(site.id), 'name' : site.name for site in region.sites.objects.all()} for region in Region.objects.all()}
```